# Define sum of square without defining parameter

Tags: f#, value-restriction

I want to define `sumOfSquares` without explicity using parameter, relying instead on functional composition

Here's my code below

```
let sumOfSquares = Seq.map (fun n -> n * n) >> Seq.sum
```

However, I got the following error

> stdin(80,5): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'sumOfSquares'
>   has been inferred to have generic type
>
> ```
> val sumOfSquares : ('_a -> int) when '_a :> seq<int>
> ```
>
> Either make the arguments to 'sumOfSquares' explicit or, if you do not intend for
>   it to be generic, add a type annotation.

One way to resolve it is by using parameters

```
let sumOfSquares nums = nums |> Seq.map (fun n -> n * n) |> Seq.sum
```

and this will work. However, I want to see if I can define sum of squares by using composition alone

**Update**

Here's a [nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) describing the issue I've encountered: Value Restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a type annotation:

```
let sumOfSquares : seq<int> -> int = 
    Seq.map (fun n -> n * n) >> Seq.sum
```

Comment: Thanks. Correct me if I'm wrong, F# assumed I'm making a function that accepts generic typed parameter but upon type inference, it detected I wanted to define `seq<int> -> int`, hence it got "confused". Is is the case?

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound As you can see from the message, F# inferred that you want a function accepting *any collection descending from `IEnumerable<int>` in the type hierarchy* and returning `int`. If you want the argument to be strictly `seq<int>`, you have to annotate it :) Unfortunately, subtyping (and also overloading) can be tricky for the type inference...

Answer (score 0):

So lets see what happens when the type inference tries to work here.  First you have

```
Seq.map (fun n -> n * n) >> Seq.sum
```

Now as `Seq` allows for anything that implements `Seq`, we can input `int list` `int[]` or many others.

As a result, you get this as the type

```
val sumOfSquares : ('_a -> int) when '_a :> seq<int>
```

Now the problem is that `sumofSquares` is a value (which is a function).  Unfortunately, you can't have a generic value in a top level binding.  You can though have a generic function, if you make the arguments explicit.

As a result, one alternative to a type annotation is to make the argument explicit like so

```
let sumOfSquares s= s |> Seq.map (fun n -> n * n) |> Seq.sum
```

And this works

Searching SO for "value restriction errors" should give some more examples of this problem.